# Combinations (repetition not allowed & order not important)

Tags: combinatorics, c, c++, pseudocode

How to compute a table of numbers (all possibilities), where **repetition is not allowed** and **order is not important**.
Example:

I have a set of prime numbers. In this example I have four: {3,5,7,11}, but it can be anything, and I want to choose every pair out of that set.
To make things easier, I want to compute the indices to get those pairs of prime numbers. The set of indices is then {0,1,2,3}. We pick 2 out of 4 elements. So how do we compute the permutations or combinations:

```
0,1   (3,5)
0,2   (3,7)
0,3   (3,11)
1,2   (5,7)
1,3   (5,11)
2,3   (7,11)
```

?

It was difficult to find examples on the web, because they either allowed repetitions or were order was important. Pls answer with pseudocode or c/c++ if you can.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in pairs of elements?

Comment: What is meant by "a table of numbers (all possibilities)"?  Can you state the task you are trying to solve more clearly?  This is not a coding site; C/C++ code is off-topic here, but algorithms and methods are appropriate.

Comment: @D.W. "Try to ask this question on cs.stackexchange.com – S.M. 21 hours ago" ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66782338/permutation-no-repetition-order-is-not-important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem interested in just **pairs** of indices. Then, if you have $n$ elements you can just generate all pairs of indices  $(i,j)$ with $0 \le i < j < n$.

```
For i=0,1,...,n-2:
   For j=i+1, i+2, ..., n-1:
      Output (i,j)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for